# ¿Como puedo meter objetos de otros paquetes en JSP?

Tags: html, jsp

Necesito usar un objeto introducido en un JSP, el problema es que cuando intento usarlo me dice que la variable "*Campeonato cannot be resolved to a type*". Supongo que debo hacer algún tipo de import, pero no se exactamente como. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Esta es la jerarquía:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<%
            Hashtable<String,Campeonato> mensaje = (Hashtable<String,Campeonato>) request.getSession().getAttribute("Resultado"); 

            if(mensaje == null) out.println("No se ha podido recuperar el mensaje de la sesion.");

            else{

                for(int i = 0; i < mensaje.size(); i++){
                    %>

                        <option value=<%mensaje.get(Integer.toString(i+1)).getIdCampeonato();%>><%mensaje.get(Integer.toString(i)).getNombreC();%></option>

                    <%
                }
            }

        %>
```

Necesito meter el objeto "*Campeonato*" en el .jsp "*Seleccion_Campeonatos*"

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: Dos consejos: Primero, añade tu código para que veamos de qué estamos hablando. Y segundo: No metas NUNCA código Java en un JSP. Que se pueda hacer no significa que se deba hacer, `<% ... %>` es una marca de que algo no se está haciendo bien

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Pablo, disculpa lo del código.

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto mi propia pregunta tan solo hay que importar con un "*page import*" antes de la etiqueta "'html" de esta manera:

```
<%@ page import="Algoritmos.*"%>
```

En un principio no me cogía esta importación. pero tras guardar el cambio ha desaparecido el error.